# No Code First option when adding new model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am following a tutorial on Code First Migrations with an existing database (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/data/dn579398).

The tutorial described when adding a new Data Model to select ADO.NET Entity Data Model. Once you click "Add" you are provided four options one being "Code First From Existing Database" which is tell you to select. The problem is I only have two options. One is "Generate From Database" and Empty Model, none of which mention Code First.

I am using VS2013 and very new to ASP and MVC. Do I need to install an SDK or some other add on.

Cheers,
Kevin.

Comment: Ok, I have tried us using the 'Generate From Database" option and all is going well...Fingers crossed

Comment: I don't think this will work. I get the following error when trying to Enable_Migrations: "Creating a DbModelBuilder or writing the EDMX from a DbContext created using Database First or Model First is not supported. EDMX can only be obtained from a Code First DbContext created without using an existing DbCompiledModel."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DB to Code First is part of the new EF 6.1 tooling. You can download it from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762  I wrote a blog post about it over here if you want to get a quick overview: http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/first-look-at-beta-of-ef-6-1-designer/

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I believe I already have EF 6.1 installed but I will take another look and read your blog.

Comment: Followed your advice and downloaded the tools for VS2013 and worked a treat. Just wanted to point out to other who may use this that when I clicked download it downloaded VS2012 version by default. You need to click on the "Click Here" link next to the "If your download does not start after 30 seconds" and select VS2013. Thanks Julie :)